# `require': cannot load such file -- rack/cache/entity_store (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

After adding redis cache gems in my app

```
gem 'redis'
gem 'redis-namespace'
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'redis-rack-cache'
```

After installing that GEM I'm getting the following error.

```
`require': cannot load such file -- rack/cache/entity_store (LoadError)
```

> How can I resolve this, Any idea ?

Comment: Do you need all of those gems? I only use `redis-rails` and it works perfectly.

Comment: its mention in tutorial
https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-model-caching-redis/

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [like](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rack-cache/issues/9), try using rack-cache version > 1.6.0

Add the following to your gem file:

```
gem 'rack-cache', '~> 1.6.1'
```

then run

```
bundle update rack-cache
```